# Coluna não encontrada ao utilizar WITH

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Olá, eu estou tentando relacionar duas tabelas com WITH:

```
$usuarios = User::with('usuario_dados')->where('usuario_dados.identidade', 'LIKE', '%' . $termo . '%')->get();
```

Mas ele me retorna o erro que a coluna identidade não existe em usuario_dados.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usuario_dados.identidade' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * fromuserswhereusuario_dados.identidadeLIKE %725%)
```

No Model USER, tenho a seguinte função:

```
public function usuario_dados(){
        return $this->hasOne(Usuario_Dado::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score -1):

No caso, o seu where está errado. Como você está querendo fazer um where da classe Usuario_Dado, você precisa fazer isto dentro do with, utilizando uma subquery. Desta forma:

```
$usuarios = User::with(['usuario_dados' => function($query){$query->where('identidade', 'LIKE', '%' . $termo . '%');}])->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

Se você reparar no SQL gerado, vai ver que ele está dando um select from na tabela USERS e dentro dela esta procurando uma coluna chamada *usuario_dados.identidade* que realmente não existe na tabela. Por isto gera o erro.

```
select * from users where usuario_dados.identidade LIKE %725%
```

O que você quer de fato é procurar todos usuario que tenham uma ligação  e você está usando o método WITH porquê ele gera um pré carregamento que ajuda em velocidade em alguns casos no Laravel. O código para isto, seria algo deste tipo:

```
$users= User::with('usuario_dados')
 ->whereHas('usuario_dados', function (Builder $query) {
  $query->where('identidade', 'like', '%' . $termo . '%');
 })
 ->get();
```

O resultado em SQL embora não conheça bem todas as tabelas citadas, é algo como isto:

```
    select * from users WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM usuario_dados WHERE users .user_id=usuario_dados.user_id and usuario_dados.identidadelike '725%');
```